# realtime uv unwrapping from view with moving or rotating of unwrapped mesh

Tags: uv, 3d-view, vertices, faces

How do I make the object vertices move or animate in the uv editor when they are moving or animating in the 3d view from a specified view in real time, such as camera view or from the top of the object in z-coordinates for example?
How can I apply this to only the faces and vertices facing the specified view?
I don't mind using Python if there are no other solutions

[image]

[image: in edit mode(3d view)]
[image: in uv map(uv) editor]

[image: in edit mode(3d view)]
[image: in uv map(uv) editor]

[image: in edit mode(3d view)]
[image: in uv map(uv) editor]

Comment: could you please show some screenshots to make it more understandable?

Comment: 4 days and nobody even wrote a single comment?

Comment: I think either people don't understand your question or have no idea how to do what you want, I guess you'll have to do via python

Comment: What I mean is that I try to make any vertice in mesh move(transform) in the uv editor when the same vertice moves in the edit mode in 3d view.This would be useful in animation, at least for me

Comment: yes but could you show one example of how the texture would show before and after, there may be a trick to do what you want

Comment: The texture remains fixed without any change in it, let's say, for example, we have a fixed cube and at the top of it has a animated texture, a fixed cube will appear with a animated texture. I want the opposite so that the cube rotates around itself, but a texture that appears fixed remains on the faces of the cube without moving with it.
The only way in my opinion is for a cube's vertices or faces to move in the uv editor the same way it moves in the 3d view, as if you placed the same cube in the uv editor.

Comment: You can make the location of the texture depend on an empty and not on the object location, on the bottom of the Texture Coordinate you have an Object field, you can choose for example an empty, if you move the object but keep the empty still, the texture will also remain still in the global space, is it what you want?

Comment: Also there is the Texture Coordinate "Camera" output, it migh be the one you're looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Texture Coordinate* could interest you:

- If you use its *Camera* output socket, it will project your image on the object surface, but the image will always face the view:

[image]

- If you use the *Object* output socket, you can choose an *Object* on the bottom of the node, here an empty, and the image location will depend on the location of your empty, not the location of your object, if you move your object, the image won't follow, if you move your empty, the image will follow:

[image]

Comment: Yes that is exactly that, thank you very much.